# Set an object's property from color picker in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, color-picker

I would like to set the property `Color` of my object `Product` to a chosen color (RGB code) from a color picker. For example : `Product.Color = #ff0000`. This code isn't working (`Color`is not set).

```
<form method="post">
<div>
    <label asp-for="Product.Color"></label>
    <input asp-for="Product.Color" type="favcolor" name="Color" value="#ff0000"/>
</div>
<button type="submit" asp-rout-id="Inventory.ProductID">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You didn't provide the complete info of how you want to implement it,i guess you can easily implement it by following this link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/colorpicker/using-the-colorpicker-control-extender-cs

Comment: @Musab I use the HTML 5 color input:

`<input type="color" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000">` (see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452325/free-asp-net-color-picker-control)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jscolor.com/examples/) solve my problem

in cshtml:

```
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
```

and if are you using @model can send information by `input asp-for="Color"`